# How can I improve a Zombie deck to work faster?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I created a deck with the new expansion (Dark Ascension) using the cards I got from a couple of boosters last week.

My initial deck form is [[Zombies Nightmare]](http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/deck.asp?deck_id=974268) (created by me) but I feel like it needs to be improved, to increase the probability of being able to play something on the first 2 turns.
I am very inexperienced (I only started a month ago) so any tips on how to make this deck more functional would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can I be the first person to say that I liked Zombie movies better when the zombies moved really slowly, rather than zooming around at high speed like they often do today? ;)

Comment: @thesunneversets I agree with you. It made the experience more thrilling specially since Zombies are supposed to be rotten bodies, so how can they move as fast (and most times faster) like we do? With that said, I love old school horror movies (most old school movies are more interesting than today's) so I share your opinion.

Comment: @thesunneversets Slow inexorable zombies is a big part of the Innistrad theme. There's a pretty good MaRo interview about it in the Channel Fireball archives.

Comment: The cards Endless Ranks of the Dead and Army of the Damned hit the zombie trope really well because they're both slow and overwhelming.

Comment: In that case, everyone, I feel like the ultimate MtG Zombie deck should not be improved to work faster, it should be improved to work slower!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a newbie that wants to improve on a deck so I won't go into deck building theory or anything like that, I'll just try to be useful and point out a possible approach (which is not the only one, by all means).

You have a nice zombie theme going on. I think you can go for a nice aggro deck with cards from the last couple expansions (Innistrad and Dark Ascension).

First of all, the focus. How do you kill? I'd say zombies are good at swarming. Let's go for overwhelming the opponent with a lot of creatures: Diregraf Ghoul, Gravecrawler are your all stars, so ideally you'd play 4 of each! Highborn Ghoul can be interesting for its evasion, Black Cat is also cheap and provides value when it dies and Geralf's Messenger is nuts although it costs too much black mana (so you just want 2 or 3).

Let's not forget some blue zombies as well! Diregraf Captain is pretty neat because it pumps all the other guys (4 of him as well), Stitched Drake is really powerful and cheap but once again, costs two blue (maybe play only 3)!

About your spells, I think they're all over the place! I'd just focus on getting rid of opposing creatures so that your zombies can hit.

Undying Evil is a neat trick to save one of your guys (plus it plays really well with Black Cat or the Captain). Other than that, you want Tragic Slip, Dead Weight or Victim of Night. If you can get your hands on other expansions I'd say Go For The Throat, Doom Blade and Dismember are all very powerful standard legal removal spells!

Finally, since you're playing blue, maybe some Ponder and Forbidden Alchemy would be good to trim your deck and get the good cards out!

Comment: thank you for explaining so much to me. As a newbie, getting info from experienced people (and also from winning and most likely losing games hehe) is all I'm searching for right now. I got some of the cards you mentioned from packs I bought from some other expansions. One last question (which I think isn't worth opening a new Question), can I play in Standard events mixing cards from other expansions with Dark Ascension? I was going only for Dark Ascension since I thought that your deck could only have cards from that expansion in order to play in a tournament. 
Glad for the help!

Comment: Standard means you can play with the last core set and the last two blocks. A block is a group of three related expansions. For example, right now you can play Scars of Mirrodin block (which is Scars of Mirrodin, Mirrodin Besieged and New Phyrexia) plus Innistrad Block (which is Innistrad and Dark Ascension) and M12. Once Avacyn Restored comes out, you'll be able to play that expansion in Standard with all the other ones I just mentioned.

Comment: thanks my friend. With the info you provided me I am able to build a much better deck. I have a ton other zombies from the blocks you mentioned!

Comment: It's unfortunate that despite the fact OP specifically mentions wanting to cast on turn 1 and turn 2, this answer doesn't mention the mana curve. It's not a difficult concept, and it does wonders for improving deck consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Army of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Army%20of%20the%20Damned), [Endless Ranks of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20Ranks%20of%20the%20Dead), [Rooftop Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rooftop%20Storm), [Undead Alchemist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Undead%20Alchemist), [Zombie Nightmare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zombie%20Nightmare) and 4 [Dark Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Ritual)s with a couple of [Gilded Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gilded%20Lotus)es and the game is practically yours.

Using just [Army of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Army%20of%20the%20Damned), [Endless Ranks of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Endless%20Ranks%20of%20the%20Dead) and 4 [Dark Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Ritual)s I've been able to bring out an endless horde of zombies (I mean 32 2/2 black zombie tokens storming the battlefield plus being able to sacrifice with them to keep alive your most valuable zombie creatures). Play [Rooftop Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rooftop%20Storm) and you can play any zombie card free of mana.